# canvas element flashing when i move it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, next.js, html5-canvas

I have a project with NextJS, and I want to create a canvas that contains svg images.
I was able to create the canvas element, add the images to it, and also implement the logic of moving one element in the canvas, but the problem is that when I drag an element, all the elements flash (because I clear the canvas and redraw the elements), and I don't know how to prevent that from happening.

jsx code :

```
 <div style={{ width: "100%", height: "calc(100% - 40px)", overflow: "scroll" }}>
      <canvas
        width={1210}
        height={495}
        style={{ backgroundColor: "#FFF" }}
        id="canvas-container"
        ref={canvasRef}
      ></canvas>
    </div>
```

The logic of draw the images and moving them :

```
const canvasRef = useRef(null);
  let [canvas, setCanvas] = useState(null);
  let [context, setContext] = useState(null);
  let [tablesState, setTablesState] = useState([]);

  function draw() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    for (const el of tablesState) {
      let image = new Image();
      switch (el.shape) {
        case "square":
          image.onload = function () {
            context.drawImage(image, el.x, el.y, 80, 80);
          };
          image.src =
            "data:image/svg+xml;base64," +
            window.btoa(`
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="140" height="140">
          <defs>
          </defs>
          <rect x="20" y="20" fill="#CCC" width="100" height="100"/>
          <text id="tableNumText" x="70" y="70" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" fill="#000" font-size="26px">${el.tableNbr}</text>
          <circle cx="115" cy="25" r="25" fill="#000"/>
          <text id="bookingInfo" x="115" y="27" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" fill="#FFF" font-weight="700"    font-size="24px">-/${el.nbrPlaces}</text>
          </svg>`);
          break;

        case "oval":
          image.onload = function () {
            context.drawImage(image, el.x, el.y, 140, 100);
          };
          image.src =
            "data:image/svg+xml;base64," +
            window.btoa(`
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="190" height="140">
        <defs>
        </defs>
        <ellipse cx="100" cy="70" rx="80" ry="50" fill = "#CCC" />
        <text id="tableNumText" x="100" y="70" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" fill="#000" font-size="26px">${el.tableNbr}</text>
        <circle cx="160" cy="30" r="25" fill="#000"/>
        <text id="bookingInfo" x="160" y="30" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" fill="#FFF" font-weight="700" font-size="24px">-/${el.nbrPlaces}</text>
        </svg>`);
          break;

        case "rectangular":
          image.onload = function () {
            context.drawImage(image, el.x, el.y, 150, 100);
          };
          image.src =
            "data:image/svg+xml;base64," +
            window.btoa(`
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="210" height="140">
        <defs>
        </defs>
        <rect width = "150" height = "100"  x="20" y="20"  fill="#CCC"/>
        <text id="tableNumText" x="95" y="70" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" fill="#000" font-size="26px">${el.tableNbr}</text>
        <circle cx="170" cy="30" r="25" fill="#000"/>
        <text id="bookingInfo" x="170" y="30" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" fill="#FFF" font-weight="700" font-size="24px">-/${el.nbrPlaces}</text>
        </svg>`);
          break;

        default: // circle
          image.onload = function () {
            context.drawImage(image, el.x, el.y, 80, 80);
          };
          image.src =
            "data:image/svg+xml;base64," +
            window.btoa(`
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="140" height="140">
      <defs>
      </defs>
      <circle cx="70" cy="70" r = "50" fill="#CCC"/>
      <text id="tableNumText" x="70" y="70" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" fill="#000" font-size="26px">${el.tableNbr}</text>
      <circle cx="110" cy="35" r="25" fill="#000"/>
      <text id="bookingInfo" x="110" y="35" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" fill="#FFF" font-weight="700" font-size="24px">-/${el.nbrPlaces}</text>
      </svg>`);
          break;
      }
    }
  }

  const hitElement = (x, y, index) => {
    let element = tablesState.find((el) => el.id === index);
    let height = element?.shape === "square" || element?.shape === "circle" ? 80 : 100;
    let width = element?.shape === "square" || element?.shape === "circle" ? 70 : 150;

    return (
      x >= element?.x && x <= element?.x + width && y >= element?.y && y <= element?.y + height
    );
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setTablesState(tables);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!canvasRef) return;

    setCanvas(canvasRef.current);
  }, [canvasRef]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!canvas) return;

    setContext(canvas.getContext("2d"));
  }, [canvas]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!context) return;

    if (!isDragging) {
      draw();
    }
    let prevX = 0;
    let prevY = 0;
    let isDragging = false;
    let selectedElement = -1;

    const handleMouseDown = (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      isDragging = true;

      prevX = event.offsetX;
      prevY = event.offsetY;

      for (var i = 0; i < tablesState.length; i++) {
        if (hitElement(prevX, prevY, i)) {
          selectedElement = i;
        }
      }
    };

    const handleMouseUp = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      isDragging = false;
      selectedElement = -1;
    };

    function handleMouseOut(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      isDragging = false;
      selectedElement = -1;
    }

    const handleMouseMove = (event) => {
      if (!isDragging || selectedElement === -1) return;
      event.preventDefault();

      let element = tablesState.find((el) => el.id === selectedElement);

      let width = element?.shape === "square" || element?.shape === "circle" ? 80 : 150;
      let height = element?.shape === "square" || element?.shape === "circle" ? 80 : 100;

      tablesState?.map((el) => {
        if (el.id === selectedElement) {
          el.x = event.offsetX - width / 2;
          el.y = event.offsetY - height / 2;
        }
        return el;
      });

      draw();
    };

    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", handleMouseDown);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", handleMouseOut);

    return () => {
      canvas.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleMouseDown);
      canvas.removeEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);
      canvas.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
      canvas.removeEventListener("mouseout", handleMouseOut);
    };
  }, [context]);
```

tablesState contains the data in this format :

```
[
  {
    id: 0,
    tableNbr: 159,
    shape: "circle",
    color: "#AAA",
    x: 50,
    y: 150,
    nbrPlaces: 2,
    isDragging: false,
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    tableNbr: 357,
    shape: "square",
    color: "#AAA",
    x: 100,
    y: 50,
    nbrPlaces: 4,
    isDragging: false,
  },... ]
```

I need any help with that guys thank you in advance

Comment: If you're drawing SVG shapes... why not just use an `<svg>`?

Comment: @AKX Because i want the shapes to be dynamic and can change their coordinates

Comment: Yes? You can render <svg> elements just like you can render divs or whatever with React.

Comment: The canvas is double buffered and  thus can not present changes until you exit execution. The problem is that you clear the canvas,  set the svg image `src`, and `onload` callbacks then exit execution (return from `Draw` function) thus presenting only the cleared canvas.  `onload` will ONLY be called after all execution in complete ie `Draw` function has exited. You should preload the SVG images and only call `Draw` after they all have loaded.

Comment: @AKX Yes i could do that but i think i will have the same problem in moving the elements.

Comment: @Blindman67 I don't know ho to do that, can you give me an example please?

Comment: @BoulanfadMustapha No, it won't have that problem if you implement it right.

Comment: @AKX can you show me how to do it please ?

Comment: @BoulanfadMustapha I have an old example of something similar here. https://codesandbox.io/s/svg-rectangle-draggy-0hy278

Comment: @AKX Yeah this example will work fine if a have simple shapes, but i use an svg images that contain a number inside and a small circle on the top-left side of the shape. I already try react-konva, raphael in diferente ways but i didn't find a way to do that

Comment: @AKX I put it in codesandbox for you https://codesandbox.io/embed/loving-monad-qc92gd?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: @BoulanfadMustapha Unfortunately I don't have the time to rework your example to use an SVG, but you really should be easily able to adapt my example to render your more complex SVG shapes as groups instead of drawing them as images.

Comment: @AKX thanks a lot man, i will try to do this again.